# How can I programmatically screenshot for iphone5?

Tags: xcode, ios6, screenshot, capture

I'm looking to have a "save" button for images in my app. The problem is, the images are blurry for iPhone 5, and for iPhone 4. This is my code I'm using now.

For iPhone 4 and 4s users its:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], CGRectMake (0, 20, self.view.bounds.size.width, (self.view.bounds.size.height - 40)));

        //save photo to photoAlbum
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved!"
                                                          message:@"Image has been Saved, don't forget to Share!"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        // Request to save the image to camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);        }
```

For iPhone 5 Users I have:

```
     if(result.height == 568)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        else
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], CGRectMake (0, 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, (self.view.bounds.size.height - 150)));

        //save photo to photoAlbum
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved!"
                                                          message:@"Image has been Saved, don't forget to Share!"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        // Request to save the image to camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to set/unset the antialising context option with `CGContextSetShouldAntialias()`?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably capturing a non-retina 320x480 screenshot. Note that the `bounds` of `UIScreen` are measured in **points**, not pixels.